# Weblogic - Get Deployment Type Using Wlst

Tags: deployment, monitoring, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I am trying to monitor the state of deployments on managed servers in a domain , using wlst.

I am using Weblogic 10.3

Here is what I have so far :

```
domainRuntime()

applnRtStEuntimeBean = cmo.getAppRuntimeStateRuntime()

servers=domainRuntimeService.getServerRuntimes()

for server in servers:
     serverName = server.getName()
     applns = server.getApplicationRuntimes();
     for appln in applns:
         print 'Application Name          #', appln.getApplicationName()
         print 'Applican Current State    #', applnRtStEuntimeBean.getCurrentState(appName,serverName)
         print 'Applican Intended State   #', applnRtStEuntimeBean.getIntendedState(appName)
```

**This gives me the current state of all applications irrespective of its "type" .
Is there a way one can filter applications by its type using wlst ?**

For instance I only want to check state of "Enterprise Application" and "Web Application" and ignore all "Library"

I have looked at the MBeans Java docs but I don't see anything that can get me the application type.

For your reference application name , type , health and state are listed in the "Deployment" page on the admin console.

Appreciate your feedback/suggestions/comments !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mohan Yes you can filter out that in two step.
You can use if condition inside the for loop and 'continue' for ignore when the library file encountered.

```
applname=['test.war','test2.ear','test3.jar']
wls:/offline> for s in applname:
... if s.endswith('jar'):
...  print 'ignore'
...  continue
... print s
    # do your task of monitoring here
...
test.war
test2.ear
ignore
```

Note that you must follow correct indentation for each block here.
HTH

Comment: The application names do not have an extension to identify them by !! Hence this would not work.

Comment: you can rename them if u want right? other wise keep list of the lib files in separate list variable. and try to skip as shown above

Comment: yes, renaming the app or having a "skiplist" will work.This should be kept as the last option . There should be a way to do this using weblogic/mbean server API. If the admin console can get this info , we should be able to do the same using WLST.